How does the fact that $\mathbb{G}^n$ is $2^n$ dimensional help show that the $\mathbb{G}^n$ norm satisfies the triangle inequality?
I'm home-studying geometric algebra from Alan Macdonald's "Linear and Geometric Algebra" textbook. Problem 6.2.1 reads

Show that the $\mathbb{G}^n$ norm satisfies the properties of the $\mathbb{R}^n$ norm given in Theorem 4.14. Hint: with the help of Problem 6.1.1, the problem can be solved with no calculations.

The other properties of the $\mathbb{R}^n$ norm were pretty easy to show, but the triangle inequality has been eluding me for weeks!
Triangle Inequality
$|\textbf{u} + \textbf{v}| \leq |\textbf{u}| + |\textbf{v}|$
$\mathbb{G}^n$ Norm
$|A|^2 = \sum\limits_{J} a^2_J$
Where the $a_J$ come from expanding the multivector $A$ with respect to a canonical basis $\{\mathbf{e}_J\}$ so that $A = \sum_J a_J \textbf{e}_J$.
But we also just learned about reverses and have another definition:
Norm (well defined)
$|A|^2 = \left<A^\dagger A\right>_0$
which means "take the $0$-vector part of the product of $A$-reverse with $A$".
and lastly, problem 6.1.1 asked me to show that $\mathbb{G}^n$ is $2^n$ dimensional which I reasoned is because there are $2^n$ ways to combine $n$ elements and you use logic like we find here: Calculate the total number of combinations over n elements, where the number of elements in each subset is in {0,..,n}?
but I have no idea how that helps me prove the triangle inequality! Each of the ways I've tried to expand the two sides of the expression have failed to help me see how the terms on left and right have any definite relation to each other (equal, greater-than etc). What am I missing?

In my copy of that book, the problem is
6.2.1. Show that if a is a scalar and B a blade, then |aB| = |a||B|.
What edition do you have?

If you understand that the $\mathbb e_J$ form a basis, then $$\sum_Ja_J\mathbb e_J \mapsto a_J^2$$ defines exactly the $\mathbb R^{2^n}$ norm. Done. You don't need to do anything else.

Nicholas Todoroff is missing a Sigma on the right.

@JohnDouma I'm using the fourth printing.

@NicholasTodoroff and (Alan Macdonald!) if I understand correctly, the point here is that because the index $J$ is going over the canonical multivector basis we get a scalar for each dimension and now the $n$ multivector dimensions have produced a set isomorphic to $2^n$  ℝ dimensions. No hard triangle inequality to prove! Is that right?

@KCE I'm not sure what you mean by "$n$ multivector dimensions", but it seems like you are thinking the right thing. You do have to prove the triangle inequality at some point, it's just that I assume you already know how to prove it for $\mathbb R^m$, and here the $\mathbb G^n$ norm is really just the case $m=2^n$. If you don't know how to do this, it's something you should think about!

Yes, thanks for saying it better! That is what I have in mind but I'm not speaking very precisely. @NicholasTodoroff do you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted? :)

Fixing a basis like $\mathbb e_J$ gives an isomorphism with $\mathbb R^{2^n}$:
$$
  \sum_Ja_J\mathbb e_J \longleftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\\vdots\\a_n\\a_{1,2}\\\vdots\\a_{1,n}\\a_{2,3}\\\vdots\\a_{n-1,n}\\\vdots\\a_{1,2,\dotsc,n}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The $\mathbb G^n$ norm
$$
  \sum_Ja_J\mathbb e_J \mapsto \sum_Ja_J^2
$$
is exactly the standard norm on this $\mathbb R^{2^n}$. Thus, if you understand how the standard $\mathbb R^m$ norm satisfies the triangle inequality for arbitrary $m$, the same argument holds here with $m=2^n$.

Ah I think I know how to rephrase my comment from before in language that makes it more clear to me, so I'll write it down in case it helps someone else. The index $J$ is over the canonical basis. The canonical basis for $\mathbb{G}^n$ has $2^n$ elements. Therefore the $\mathbb{G}^n$ norm is the standard $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$ norm.
